# WriteConsoleOutputCharacter in c++ loads of ?s on console

Tags: c++, console-application

So I am following this tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xW8skO7MFYw and I am new to accessing console buffer and that. I started debugging when I realized my console looked like this https://ibb.co/896tGGL when I ran it. And I narrowed it down to this line of code

```
WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, nScreenWidth * nScreenheight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
```

the values in this are set to:

`HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);`

`wchar_t* screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth * nScreenheight];`

```
int nScreenWidth = 120;
int nScreenheight = 40;
```

`DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;`

Comment: It looks as if you haven't initialised your `screen` array. Did you do that? What output were you expecting to see?

Comment: I am expecting to see https://ibb.co/R4rwc6G and i thought the line i included above was initializing screen. is it not?

Comment: So you should show the code where you put those characters into your `screen` array. You probably made a mistake in that part of your code.

Comment: The line above is allocating the array but it's not initialising it's content to anything, certainly not to a bunch of `#`.

Comment: int nCeiling = (float)(nScreenheight / 2.0) - nScreenheight / ((float)fDistanceToWall);
            int nFloor = nScreenheight - nCeiling;

            for (int y = 0; y < nScreenheight; y++) {

                if (y < nCeiling)
                    screen[y * nScreenWidth] = ' ';

                else if (y > nCeiling && y <= nFloor)
                    screen[y * nScreenWidth] = '#';
                else
                    screen[y * nScreenWidth] = ' ';
            }
        }

        screen[nScreenWidth * nScreenheight - 1] = '\0';

Comment: this code checks where the ceiling and floor is and then outputs # or ' ' accordingly

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Reverse engineering your code is not my idea of fun.

Answer (score 0):

All the parts of your code that say

```
screen[y * nScreenWidth] = something;
```

should be

```
screen[y * nScreenWidth + x] = something;
```

And of course you need to loop to set the `x` coordinate.

If you look carefully you can actually see the `#` on the left edge of your screen. That's because you missed the x ccordinate out of your calculations.